# Selenium remote webdriver error (Connection refused)

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
import sys
import os
cwd = os.getcwd()
driver= webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities=webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME,command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4444')
driver.get('http://www.google.com')
```

error:

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 61] Connection refused>
```

this program works a while ago, but now it does not. this is why I think it is a system error. (OSX 10.13.4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you've started the [Selenium Standalone Server](https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/):

```
java -jar /path/to/selenium-server-standalone-<version>.jar
```

You should see output which looks something like this:

```
Jun 06, 2018 6:47:59 PM org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher main
INFO: Launching a standalone server
18:47:59.720 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 24.171-b02
18:47:59.722 INFO - OS: Linux 3.13.0-149-generic amd64
18:47:59.731 INFO - v2.13.0, with Core v2.13.0. Built from revision 14793
18:47:59.889 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
18:47:59.891 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
18:47:59.892 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]
18:47:59.893 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
18:47:59.893 INFO - Started HttpContext[/,/]
18:47:59.915 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@6c15f918
18:47:59.915 INFO - Started HttpContext[/wd,/wd]
18:47:59.919 INFO - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:4444
18:47:59.919 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@606145c5
```

Notice, in particular the line which reads:

```
RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
```

Use this URL in `command_executor`:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Remote(
    desired_capabilities=webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME,
    command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub')
driver.get('http://www.google.com')
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the *API Docs* the [**Remote WebDriver**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver) implementation is as follows:

```
class selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver(command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub', desired_capabilities=None, browser_profile=None, proxy=None, keep_alive=False, file_detector=None, options=None)
```

An [**example**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities):

```
# Instantiate an instance of Remote WebDriver with the desired capabilities.
driver = webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities=capabilities, command_executor=selenium_grid_url)
```

So you need to change the line of code from:

```
driver= webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities=webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME,command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4444')
```

To:

```
driver= webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities().CHROME,command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4444')
```